# Transparent screenshot with Firefox selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

## In short

I want to take a screenshot of an element without the background with `selenium.webdriver.Firefox`

## Actual behaviour

[image: Actual behaviour]

## Expected / desired behaviour

[image]

## My code

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from PIL import Image

CSS_SELECTOR = ".RNNXgb"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://google.com")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(CSS_SELECTOR)

image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(element.screenshot_as_png))
image.save("myscreenshot.png", "png")

driver.quit()
```

## Things not working (not suitable for this situation)

### Replacing white with transparent pixels

This does not work because it replaces the white in the element too

```py
def remove_color(img, rgba):
    data = np.array(img.convert('RGBA'))        # rgba array from image
    pixels = data.view(dtype=np.uint32)[...,0]  # pixels as rgba uint32
    data[...,3] = np.where(pixels == np.uint32(rgba), np.uint8(0), np.uint8(255))  # set alpha channel
    return Image.fromarray(data)
image = replace_color(image, 0xffffffff)
```

### Settings trasparent background

It does nothing

```py
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('hplogo').style.background = 'transparent'")
```

### Use of DevTools API

Only for Chromium, not Firefox

Comment: you misspelled transparent.

Comment: @MZ thanks, I changed the example.